# why is the landscape mode view still show width less then height?

Tags: iphone, landscape

try this,

say you have a simple landscape mode iphone app, like a simple viewcontroller app.

also uncomment the autorotate in viewcontroller .m file like so

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
  NSLOG(@"width:%f,height:%f",self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
  return YES;
}
```

after that, simply run the thing on iphone simulator, and try to rotate it by command+left or command+right.

I would expect that I get something like width:320.000,height:480.000 when in portrait and width:480.000,height:320.000  in the landscape mode.

instead, i always got width:320.000,height:480.000 what ever the actual orientation is.

so my question is what should i automatically get the view's size correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the width/height in:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation 

{
  NSLog(@"view frame: %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));
}
```

Also your view needs to have UIAutoresizingMasks set in order to resize when rotated.